# Multiple JSliders activating and deactivating - Sharing values

Tags: java, swing, awt, jslider

**Context**

Im writing a piece of code that has 1+ Sliders. These sliders form a group. The sum of the slider values of this group must always be 100. However, as a NEEDED feature, the user can disable and enable (add/remove) sliders from this group. Therefore, this requires that the sliders values get adjusted properly.

After attempting to code my own group, I decided to look for a better/tested and implemented code. It improved from mine, however, some issues appeared.

---

**Primary Issue**

Adding or removing sliders by selection or deselection the checkbox causes errors and the sliders stop working. Notice that adding, in this scenario, just means enabling a previously disabled slider (by deselecting the checkbox).

[image: Example of the current issue]

---

**Preliminary Solution**

The code below was found in stackoverflow. I did implement in my code but since I cant post it, I decided to adjust the code found in the stackoverflow example to represent my scenario.

---

**How to?**

Any help is greatly appreciated. Im not sure how to approach the fix for this problem without causing more errors. I did try re-adjusting the calculus done on the update method but it just caused more nonsense. I dont find productive posting all my attempts here because stackoverflow would say its too much code and because im not sure it would help with finding an answer.

**References**

https://stackoverflow.com/a/21391448/2280645

---

```
import java.awt.GridLayout;
import java.awt.event.ItemEvent;
import java.awt.event.ItemListener;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.LinkedList;
import java.util.Map;
import javax.swing.JCheckBox;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JSlider;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;
import javax.swing.event.ChangeEvent;
import javax.swing.event.ChangeListener;

public class ConnectedSliders {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                createAndShowGUI();
            }
        });
    }

    private static void createAndShowGUI() {
        JSlider s0 = new JSlider(0, 100, 30);
        JSlider s1 = new JSlider(0, 100, 40);
        JSlider s2 = new JSlider(0, 100, 30);

        SliderGroup sliderGroup = new SliderGroup();
        //sliderGroup.add(s0);
        //sliderGroup.add(s1);
        //sliderGroup.add(s2);

        JPanel panel = new JPanel(new GridLayout(0, 3));
        panel.add(s0);
        panel.add(createListeningLabel(s0));
        panel.add(createCheckBox(s0, sliderGroup));

        panel.add(s1);
        panel.add(createListeningLabel(s1));
        panel.add(createCheckBox(s1, sliderGroup));

        panel.add(s2);
        panel.add(createListeningLabel(s2));
        panel.add(createCheckBox(s2, sliderGroup));

        panel.add(createListeningLabel(s0, s1, s2));

        JFrame f = new JFrame();
        f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        f.getContentPane().add(panel);
        f.pack();
        f.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        f.setVisible(true);
    }

    private static JLabel createListeningLabel(final JSlider... sliders) {
        final JLabel label = new JLabel("");
        for (JSlider slider : sliders) {
            slider.addChangeListener(new ChangeListener() {
                @Override
                public void stateChanged(ChangeEvent e) {
                    int sum = 0;
                    for (JSlider slider : sliders) {
                        sum += slider.getValue();
                    }
                    label.setText("Sum: " + sum);
                }
            });
        }
        return label;
    }

    private static JLabel createListeningLabel(final JSlider slider) {
        final JLabel label = new JLabel("");
        slider.addChangeListener(new ChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void stateChanged(ChangeEvent e) {
                label.setText(String.valueOf(slider.getValue()));
            }
        });
        return label;
    }

    private static JCheckBox createCheckBox(final JSlider slider, SliderGroup group) {
        final JCheckBox checkBox = new JCheckBox();
        checkBox.setSelected(true);

        checkBox.addItemListener(new ItemListener() {
            @Override
            public void itemStateChanged(ItemEvent e) {
                if (e.getStateChange() == ItemEvent.SELECTED) {
                    group.add(slider);
                    slider.setEnabled(true);
                } else if(e.getStateChange() == ItemEvent.DESELECTED) {
                    group.remove(slider);
                    slider.setEnabled(false);
                }
            }
        });

        return checkBox;

    }

}

class SliderGroup {

    private final Map<JSlider, Integer> values;
    private final LinkedList<JSlider> candidates;

    private final ChangeListener changeListener;
    private boolean updating = false;

    SliderGroup() {
        this.values = new HashMap<JSlider, Integer>();
        this.candidates = new LinkedList<JSlider>();

        changeListener = new ChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void stateChanged(ChangeEvent e) {
                JSlider source = (JSlider) e.getSource();
                update(source);
            }
        };
    }

    private void update(JSlider source) {
        if (updating) {
            return;
        }
        updating = true;

        int delta = source.getValue() - values.get(source);
        if (delta > 0) {
            distributeRemove(delta, source);
        } else {
            distributeAdd(delta, source);
        }

        for (JSlider slider : candidates) {
            values.put(slider, slider.getValue());
        }

        updating = false;
    }

    private void distributeRemove(int delta, JSlider source) {
        int counter = 0;
        int remaining = delta;
        while (remaining > 0) {
            JSlider slider = candidates.removeFirst();
            counter++;

            if (slider == source) {
                candidates.addLast(slider);
            } else {
                if (slider.getValue() > 0) {
                    slider.setValue(slider.getValue() - 1);
                    remaining--;
                    counter = 0;
                }
                candidates.addLast(slider);
                if (remaining == 0) {
                    break;
                }
            }
            if (counter > candidates.size()) {
                String message = "Can not distribute " + delta + " among " + candidates;
                //System.out.println(message);
                //return;
                throw new IllegalArgumentException(message);
            }
        }
    }

    private void distributeAdd(int delta, JSlider source) {
        int counter = 0;
        int remaining = -delta;
        while (remaining > 0) {
            JSlider slider = candidates.removeLast();
            counter++;

            if (slider == source) {
                candidates.addFirst(slider);
            } else {
                if (slider.getValue() < slider.getMaximum()) {
                    slider.setValue(slider.getValue() + 1);
                    remaining--;
                    counter = 0;
                }
                candidates.addFirst(slider);
                if (remaining == 0) {
                    break;
                }
            }
            if (counter > candidates.size()) {
                String message = "Can not distribute " + delta + " among " + candidates;
                //System.out.println(message);
                //return;
                throw new IllegalArgumentException(message);
            }
        }
    }

    void add(JSlider slider) {
        candidates.add(slider);
        values.put(slider, slider.getValue());
        slider.addChangeListener(changeListener);
    }

    void remove(JSlider slider) {
        candidates.remove(slider);
        values.remove(slider);
        slider.removeChangeListener(changeListener);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With a minor adjustment of the example that you linked to, this should be doable.

The basic idea is to not only have the `SliderGroup#add` and `remove` methods that are used for constructing the group initially, but also `addAndAdjust` and `removeAndAdjust` methods that (in addition to adding/removing the slider) distribute the value of the slider that was added or removed, using the same methods that adjusted the sliders originally only when the value of one slider changed.

I also added a `keepOneSelected` method for the check boxes: If **all** sliders could be disabled, then there is none to have the remaining value. So the method makes sure that at least one of the check boxes remains always checked.

<sub>(Edited based on the discussion in the comments:)</sub>

```
import java.awt.GridLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.util.LinkedList;

import javax.swing.JCheckBox;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JSlider;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;
import javax.swing.event.ChangeEvent;
import javax.swing.event.ChangeListener;

public class ConnectedSlidersExt
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(() -> createAndShowGUI());
    }

    private static void createAndShowGUI()
    {
        JSlider s0 = new JSlider(0, 100, 33);
        JSlider s1 = new JSlider(0, 100, 33);
        JSlider s2 = new JSlider(0, 100, 34);

        int expectedSum = 100;
        SliderGroup sliderGroup = new SliderGroup(expectedSum);
        sliderGroup.add(s0);
        sliderGroup.add(s1);
        sliderGroup.add(s2);

        JPanel panel =new JPanel(new GridLayout(0,3));
        panel.add(s0);
        panel.add(createListeningLabel(s0));
        JCheckBox checkBox0 = createCheckBox(s0, sliderGroup);
        panel.add(checkBox0);
        panel.add(s1);
        panel.add(createListeningLabel(s1));
        JCheckBox checkBox1 = createCheckBox(s1, sliderGroup);
        panel.add(checkBox1);
        panel.add(s2);
        panel.add(createListeningLabel(s2));
        JCheckBox checkBox2 = createCheckBox(s2, sliderGroup);
        panel.add(checkBox2);

        keepOneSelected(checkBox0, checkBox1, checkBox2);

        panel.add(createListeningLabel(s0, s1, s2));

        JFrame f = new JFrame();
        f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        f.getContentPane().add(panel);
        f.pack();
        f.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        f.setVisible(true);
    }

    private static void keepOneSelected(JCheckBox ...checkBoxes)
    {
        ActionListener actionListener = new ActionListener()
        {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
            {
                int numSelected = 0;
                for (JCheckBox checkBox : checkBoxes)
                {
                    if (checkBox.isSelected())
                    {
                        numSelected++;
                    }
                }
                if (numSelected == 1)
                {
                    for (int i = 0; i < checkBoxes.length; i++)
                    {
                        JCheckBox checkBox = checkBoxes[i];
                        if (checkBox.isSelected())
                        {
                            checkBox.setEnabled(false);
                        }
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    for (int i = 0; i < checkBoxes.length; i++)
                    {
                        JCheckBox checkBox = checkBoxes[i];
                        checkBox.setEnabled(true);
                    }
                }
            }
        };
        for (JCheckBox checkBox : checkBoxes)
        {
            checkBox.addActionListener(actionListener);
        }
    }

    private static JCheckBox createCheckBox(
        JSlider slider, SliderGroup group)
    {
        JCheckBox checkBox = new JCheckBox();
        checkBox.setSelected(true);
        checkBox.addActionListener(new ActionListener()
        {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
            {
                if (checkBox.isSelected())
                {
                    slider.setEnabled(true);
                    group.addAndAdjust(slider);
                }
                else
                {
                    slider.setEnabled(false);
                    group.removeAndAdjust(slider);
                }
            }
        });

        return checkBox;

    }

    private static JLabel createListeningLabel(final JSlider ... sliders)
    {
        final JLabel label = new JLabel("");
        for (JSlider slider : sliders)
        {
            slider.addChangeListener(new ChangeListener()
            {
                @Override
                public void stateChanged(ChangeEvent e)
                {
                    int sum = 0;
                    for (JSlider slider : sliders)
                    {
                        if (slider.isEnabled())
                        {
                            sum += slider.getValue();
                        }
                    }
                    label.setText("Sum: "+sum);
                }
            });
        }
        return label;
    }

    private static JLabel createListeningLabel(final JSlider slider)
    {
        final JLabel label = new JLabel("");
        slider.addChangeListener(new ChangeListener()
        {
            @Override
            public void stateChanged(ChangeEvent e)
            {
                label.setText(String.valueOf(slider.getValue()));
            }
        });
        return label;
    }


}


class SliderGroup
{
    private final int expectedSum;
    private final LinkedList<JSlider> candidates;

    private final ChangeListener changeListener;
    private boolean updating = false;

    SliderGroup(int expectedSum)
    {
        this.expectedSum = expectedSum;
        this.candidates = new LinkedList<JSlider>();

        changeListener = new ChangeListener()
        {
            @Override
            public void stateChanged(ChangeEvent e)
            {
                JSlider source = (JSlider)e.getSource();
                update(source);
            }
        };
    }

    private void update(JSlider source)
    {
        if (updating)
        {
            return;
        }
        updating = true;

        for (JSlider slider : candidates)
        {
            slider.setValueIsAdjusting(true);
        }

        if (candidates.size() > 1)
        {
            int delta = computeSum() - expectedSum;
            if (delta > 0)
            {
                distributeRemove(delta, source);
            }
            else
            {
                distributeAdd(delta, source);
            }
        }

        for (JSlider slider : candidates)
        {
            slider.setValueIsAdjusting(false);
        }

        updating = false;
    }


    private void distributeRemove(int delta, JSlider source)
    {
        int counter = 0;
        int remaining = delta;
        while (remaining > 0)
        {
            //System.out.println("remove "+remaining);

            JSlider slider = candidates.removeFirst();
            counter++;

            if (slider == source)
            {
                candidates.addLast(slider);
            }
            else
            {
                if (slider.getValue() > 0)
                {
                    slider.setValue(slider.getValue()-1);
                    remaining--;
                    counter = 0;
                }
                candidates.addLast(slider);
                if (remaining == 0)
                {
                    break;
                }
            }
            if (counter > candidates.size())
            {
                String message =
                    "Can not distribute " + delta + " among " + candidates;
                // System.out.println(message);
                // return;
                throw new IllegalArgumentException(message);
            }
        }
    }

    private void distributeAdd(int delta, JSlider source)
    {
        int counter = 0;
        int remaining = -delta;
        while (remaining > 0)
        {
            //System.out.println("add "+remaining);

            JSlider slider = candidates.removeLast();
            counter++;

            if (slider == source)
            {
                candidates.addFirst(slider);
            }
            else
            {
                if (slider.getValue() < slider.getMaximum())
                {
                    slider.setValue(slider.getValue()+1);
                    remaining--;
                    counter = 0;
                }
                candidates.addFirst(slider);
                if (remaining == 0)
                {
                    break;
                }
            }
            if (counter > candidates.size())
            {
                String message =
                    "Can not distribute " + delta + " among " + candidates;
                // System.out.println(message);
                // return;
                throw new IllegalArgumentException(message);
            }
        }
    }

    private int computeSum()
    {
        int sum = 0;
        for (JSlider slider : candidates)
        {
            sum += slider.getValue();
        }
        return sum;
    }

    void add(JSlider slider)
    {
        candidates.add(slider);
        slider.addChangeListener(changeListener);
    }

    void remove(JSlider slider)
    {
        candidates.remove(slider);
        slider.removeChangeListener(changeListener);
    }

    void addAndAdjust(JSlider slider)
    {
        add(slider);
        if (candidates.size() == 2)
        {
            update(candidates.get(0));
        }
        else
        {
            update(slider);
        }
    }

    void removeAndAdjust(JSlider slider)
    {
        remove(slider);
        update(slider);
        if (candidates.size() == 1)
        {
            JSlider candidate = candidates.get(0);
            int max = candidate.getMaximum();
            candidate.setValue(Math.min(max, expectedSum));
        }
    }


}
```

Comment: Marco, some bugs are happening with that code. For example, when Having 3 sliders with the values {33,33,34} if you mess a bit with the sliders, some errors come up. Can you help me ? please

Comment: I added a bounty as a thanks for the help. But I really need to fix this code.

Comment: The error basically happens when there are three sliders. - Disable 1 Slider, put the 2nd slider at the maximum value(100), disable the third slider which should now be zero. Put the 2nd slider at the value 50. Enable the third slider. The issue will happen.

Comment: When there are three sliders and they should sum up to 100, then disabling 2 of them (via their checkbox) should *also* disable the last one: It **has** to stay at 100, otherwise the sum will not be 100 any more. I edited the example to handle this case.

Comment: I see. I think I Didnt realize that case properly. In reality, whyen theres just 1 slider, it should remain enabled but with the value at 100.

Comment: When it should remain enabled, what should happen if its value is set to 50? Then the sum will no longer be 100....

Comment: I understand.. However the model requires to be that way.. Any ideas?

Comment: After we finish fixing all that, we should put all this into the answer. Im sure you will get a lot of attention

Comment: It's still not clear. Imagine you have 3 sliders, with values 33,33,34. Then 2 of them are disabled, therefore the last one will have a value of 100 then. Now you change this value to 50. Then you enable the first slider. What should the result be?

Comment: Exactly. When you enable the first slider, then it should have the remaining value to result in a sum of 100.

Comment: Do you think theres a way to do it?

Comment: Bits are only bits, so of course there is a way to do this. However, just to be clear: You have three sliders, with values 0,0,100, and disable the first two. Then you set the value of the last slider to 25. Then you enable the first one, and its value should jump to 75 (so that the first and the last have a sum of 100)? If so: That's a bit odd. I wonder in which case this could make sense. But if you *really* intended this, I'd try to update the answer accordingly...

Comment: Suppose 3 Sliders. If there are 2 or more sliders. The sum should be 100. If there is only 1 slider, it should be enabled but with the value set at 100. Once another slider is enabled, the values can be adjusted to sum up 100.

Comment: This is still somewhat underspecified. You say that "the values can be adjusted", but the crucial point is: **How** should the values be distributed among the sliders? When a previously disabled slider is enabled, should the one that was previously *enabled* be adjusted, or only the one that is *now* enabled? However, I have updated the answer with another attempt.

Comment: the enabled slider should be the one to be adjusted

Comment: The one that already **was** enabled, or the one that became enabled by activating the checkbox? (I mean, it's not sooo hard to be precise. Give it a try...)

Comment: "You may award your bounty in 1 hour." Thanks a lot. The way it is should work perfectly.